# On Ubuntu 14.04, the system switches off 2 minutes after started

Tags: 14.04

I was using Ubuntu to work and after an update where the system asked to restart I choose restart after. A few moments after that, my computer turned off by itself. And since then, each time I log on in Ubuntu, after a few minutes my computer turns off. 
Any idea of what should I do besides reinstall Ubuntu?

Thanks in advance for your responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to check your [syslog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog).

You can find it going to

```
/var/log
```

This file will give you more information about the issue that cause the switch off, and if you'd post it here it will provide useful information to analyze the problem.
You should check the events right before the switching off.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Apparently the problem is solved without doing anything so it's good :).